# How to return an instance of an object from a method in java

Tags: java, oop, object, types, return

I'm not sure how to return an instance of an object from a method with values. Is there some way to convert an int type into my object type? 
Here is some instructions I have:

```
/* Design a class named Location for locating a maximal value and its location in a
two-dimensional array. The class contains:

-Public double type data field maxValue that stores the maximal value in a two-dimensional
 array
-Public int type data fields row and column that store the maxValue indices in a
 two-dimensional array

Write a the following method that returns the location of the largest element in a two
dimensional array:

    public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a)

The return value is an instance of Location. Write a test program that prompts the user to
enter a two-dimensional array and displays the location of the largest element in the
array. Here is a sample run:

Enter the number of rows and columns in the array: 3 4
Enter the array:
23.5 35 2 10
4.5 3 45 3.5
35 44 5.5 9.6
The location of the largest element is 45 at (1, 2) */
```

And here is my code:

```
class Location {

    public static double maxValue;
    public static int row;
    public static int column;

    public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a) {

        maxValue = a[0][0];
        row = 0;
        column = 0;

        Location result = new Location();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

                if(a[i][j] > maxValue) {

                    maxValue = a[i][j];
                    row =  i;
                    column = j;

                    if((i == a.length-1) && (j == a[i].length-1))
                        //Place indices of maxValue in result variable
                }

                else
                    continue;

            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I should just create a constructor for Location that takes arguments, but I'm reluctant because the instructions didn't say to do so. Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can add a parameterized constructor and create a `Location`. I don't think it would be incorrect. You should confirm with your lecturer though :)

Comment: @TheLostMind yeah I thought so, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is, you are using `static` fields for an `Object`:

```
public static double maxValue;
public static int row;
public static int column;
```

Each time you call

```
public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a)
```

You think that you are creating a new `Location` object with different `maxValue`, `row` and `column` but because these fields are `static` you are just overriding class variables.
Just remove `static` modifier.

Comment: Oh yes that is true thanks! I was actually trying to figure out if there was a way to put the values of "row" and "column" in the returned instance of "Location". But I just realized my stupid mistake. I forgot that if I create an object in the main method, I can call the method as "object.locateLargest" and just use "object.variable" to access the values.